# Concatenating strings together from an array, limiting character repetitions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings that I need to concatenate to produce one string, but applying a specific number known as the `associatedNumber`. The `associatedNumber` determines that in the final output all groupings of the same character (as coming from the array) must be no longer than this `associatedNumber`.

### Example 1

```
output = [
  'MMM', 'GG', 'MM',
  'MM',  'XX', 'A',
  'B',   'D',  'M',
  'Z'
]
```

I need the output to be:

```
MMMGGMMMXXABDMZ
```

### My code

The code I have is:

```
output = [
  'MMM', 'GG', 'MM',
  'MM',  'XX', 'A',
  'B',   'D',  'M',
  'Z'
]
associatedNumber = 3;

for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    if (output[i] === associatedNumber);
    output.splice(i,1);
}
console.log(output)
```

### Example 2

```
output = [
  'HHHH', 'DDD',
  'DD',   'HH',
  'J',    'L',
  'M'
]
```

should equal:

```
HHHDDDHHJLM
```

Comment: So your variable `output` really is the input?

Comment: Yes, technically. I've gone through the work of sorting it this far but in scope of StackOverflow to keep questions specific I did just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate the array to one string, and then replace the character groups that are too long with a group of maximum length. You can use a regular expression to do that replacement:

```js
function toString(arr, maxSame) {
   let regex = RegExp(`((.)\\2{${maxSame-1}})\\2+`, "g");
   return arr.join("").replace(regex, "$1");
}

let arr = [
  'MMM', 'GG', 'MM',
  'MM',  'XX', 'A',
  'B',   'D',  'M',
  'Z'
];
console.log(toString(arr, 3));
```

Comment: I'm guessing the second `MMM` should be `MM` based on the pattern he is describing.

Comment: Why should we guess? The OP has provided the desired output, and it is `MMM`.

Answer (score 0):

`output.join().replace(/,/g, '')`

```js
output = [
  'MMM', 'GG', 'MM',
  'MM',  'XX', 'A',
  'B',   'D',  'M',
  'Z'
]
newString = output.join().replace(/,/g, '')

console.log(newString)
```

MDN Reference:
[.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
[.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This does not use the concept of the associatedNumber.

Comment: BTW, using `replace` to just remove the comma is a very verbose way to just do `join("")`. And let's hope none of the strings in the array already have commas...

Answer (score 0):

You could take various methods to join, match, map and join the string.

```js
function x(array, max) {
    return array
        .join('')
        .match(/(.)\1*/g)
        .map(s => s.slice(0, max))
        .join('');
}

console.log(x(['MMM', 'GG', 'MM', 'MM', 'XX', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'M', 'Z'], 3));
```